# Flutter: Crashlytics could not find the resource file generated by Google Services

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, kotlin, crashlytics

I got this issue after remove Kotlin on my Flutter project. I tried creating a new fresh Flutter project only supporting Java and brought my files. Got exactly the same.

I tried to run

```
android/gradlew :app:processProdReleaseGoogleServices
```

and

```
android/gradlew :app:processDevReleaseGoogleServices
```

but nothing seems to work.

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.   
> Crashlytics could not find the resource file generated by Google Services. You may need to execute the :process<Variant>GoogleServices Task. Please check your Firebase project configuration (https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
```

Before removing Kotlin, Crashlytics was working fine and app was compiling without errors so the configuration it's ok.

Comment: Have you got any solution on this. I am also facing same issue but for android native.

Comment: yes but I fixed it by creating a new project without Kotlin support